# Assigning Macro Buttons in Different Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to move a worksheet that has macro buttons (unassigned when moved) to a new workbook and then assign the buttons to some macros that are stored within the sheet. I'm using the following code to assign the macro called sort:

```
Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
set ws = OldBook.Sheets(1)

ws.Move Before:=NewBook.Sheets("Sheet Name")
NewBook.Sheets(1).Shapes.Range(Array("Button1")).Select
Selection.OnAction = "Sheet1.sort"

NewBook.SaveAs Filename:= "File Name", FileFormat:=52
NewBook.Close
```

The issue: when I run the code and then open the new workbook, the macro button is assigned to a macro called "OldBook.Sheet1.sort" which obviously doesn't exist in the new workbook.

I cannot figure out why it is tacking on the "OldBoook." when assigning the macro. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe add a workbook reference?

Comment: `.OnAction = "'" & NewBook.Name & "'!Sheet1.sort"`

Comment: That worked! Thanks SJR and Siddharth!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code Siddharth recommended in the comments worked perfectly.